Merge [tag:eq], [tag:equalization] and [tag:equalizer]
The tags eq, equalization and equalizer seem synonymous. Let's merge them?

I personally am not sure, because equalizer refers to the unit while equalization refers to the effect and eq can be used for both as a more general tag. I can see them all being used. But none have usage guidance excerpts, so maybe it would be better to write usage guidance excerpts for them, or maybe we could synonymise eq into one of the other two. Probably equalization would be best.
Saying that, there is no compressor but there is a compression... and what the hell is use-of-compression?? How did that happen? There is a amplifier but no amplification but there is a preamp. So there is not really a clear precedence I can find. Maybe that's something else we need to look at, because I think consistency is important.
There are only 7 questions on equalizer, but to me, it is a legitimate tag. Maybe see what others say.
